# Cannot compile a simple c-program using gtk-lib

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, gtk3

I am trying to implement a graphic userinterface to my c-programs. To that i have installed the GTK3.0-pacakge to my computer and followed the tutorial. But I am not able to compile a simple c-program that shows a 200*200 px window.

According to the tutorial one should compile like this:

```
gcc base.c -o base ‘pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0‘
```

Where base.c is the actual program and pkg-config is the program in the bin-folder that tells the compiler where to find the header-files and libraries.

If I just test if the pkg-config-file is there I write its name in the cmd-window:

```
pkg-config
```

I get the following answer:

*Must specify package names on the command line*

So I actually have this config-file.

But when I try to compile base.c with the above syntax that is

```
gcc base.c -o base pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
```

I get the following errors

gcc: error: pkg-config: No such file or directory

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--clfags'

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--libs'

gcc: error: gtk+-3.0: no such file or directory

So why do I get these compilation errors?

Have I missunderstood what is shown in the tutorial? Is the compilation syntax just an abbreviation of what one should do?

Comment: You are missing the backticks around `pkg-config ...`...

Comment: (Read up on shell command substitution.)

Answer (score 2):

You've just wrongly understood the tutorial. In you string disappeared the back ticks which are vital.

That means, the right line is

```
gcc base.c -o base `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Compare to your (**wrong**) line:

```
gcc base.c -o base pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
```

All the staff starting with `pkg-config` is an independent command, not a flag for `gcc`.

Back ticks tell the shell to run its contents in a subshell and substantiate the result of the command run in the gcc command line.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the question - but how does a backtick look like (how do one generate those in the CMD-window) ?. I GET EXACTLY THE SAME ERRORS USING WHAT LOOK LIKES A BACKTICK ... -> `

Comment: Well, I don't have a windows keyboard here... In bash shell you can use $() construction instead. Like gcc base.c -o base $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) But .. do you mean you are trying to work under Windows???

Comment: Yes - maybe I missunderstood EVERYTHING!!!! Is all this about working on a LINUX platform? ;-( Sitting on Windows XP :-O

Comment: It won't work in Windows Cmd. If Linux virtual/real box is unavailable, install Cygwin and use it's shell. Linux is preferable.